# Why does friend function found successfully via ADL

Tags: c++, friend

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    friend void foo(A a){ printf("3\n"); }
};

int main()
{ 
    foo(A());
}
```

It works. But I thought that this code is invalid. It is because 3.4.1/3:

> For purposes of determining (during parsing) whether an expression is
>   a postfix-expression for a function call, the **usual name lookup rules**
>   apply.

Usual name lookup rules could not find the friend function because name declared by friend is invisible in the global namespace in my case. Actually 3.3.1/4:

> friend declarations (11.3) may introduce a (possibly not visible) name
>   into an enclosing namespace

This implies that the programm is ill-formed. It is because that there is no name which found during the determining is the expression `foo(A());` is a postfix-expression for a function call.

I'm confusing...

Comment: You have the answer in the title. What are you actually asking?

Comment: I'll try to make this clear, I hope I got it right. If not let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: @juanchopanza Because foo is not visible for usual name lookup. This implies that ADL doesn't apply to foo(A()).

Comment: @juanchopanza As I've understood ADL strating to apply after usual name lookup only. But usual name lookup cannot find friend function declaration.

Comment: Friend functions defined inside class body are not considered in the scope of the enclosing class, they are in file scope

Answer (score 4):

When parsing the following program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int foo;

class A
{
public:
   operator int(){
    return 42;
   }
};

int main()
{ 
    cout << foo(A());
}
```

the output will be `42` because 3.4.1/3

> For purposes of determining (during parsing) whether an expression is
>   a postfix-expression for a function call, the usual name lookup rules
>   apply.

that means: to determine if `foo` is a postfix-expression (e.g. a cast) or a function call, the compiler will first use name lookup and search for it in the global namespace and/or enclosing scopes / base classes (or with fully qualified lookups if available).

Now take this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
   friend int foo(A a){ return 55; }

   operator int(){
    return 42;
   }
};

int main()
{ 
    cout << foo(A());
}
```

The above will output `55` thanks to [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup): foo will be found by searching inside the scopes defined by its potential arguments, i.e. A.

A friend declaration introduces a (possibly not visible) name as you posted (3.3.1/4)

> friend declarations (11.3) may introduce a (possibly not visible) name
>   into an enclosing namespace

that means the following code will not work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
   friend int foo(A a){ return 55; }

   operator int(){
    return 42;
   }
};

int main()
{ 
    cout << ::foo(A()); // Not found
    cout << A::foo(A()); // Not found
}
```

You might want to search for "**friend name injection**" and/or the [Barton-Nackman trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick). 
Short story: now ordinary lookups can't find friend declarations.

So the code you posted is well-formed because ADL allows it to run as I explained in the previous passages.

Comment: You don't ask my question. foo is not visible for usual name lookup.

Comment: Or claraify what usual name lookup does mean?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv This is normal name lookup (NOT ADL): http://stackoverflow.com/a/2604079/1938163 . Foo is not being found without ADL because of the friend hidden scope, you can think of it more or like as a subscope. ADL means = search through all subscopes of the arguments' scopes. Read carefully the explanation