# how to overload operator == outside template class using friend function?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword, friend

I'm trying to write a template class which overloads **operator==**. I know how to get it inside the class:

```
    template <typename T>
    class Point
    {
    private:
        T x;
    public:
        Point(T X) : x(X) {}

        bool operator== (Point &cP)
        {
            return (cP.x == x);
        }
    };
```

But now I want to achieve this outside the template class. I've read this post:
[error when trying to overload << operator and using friend function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883962/error-when-trying-to-overload-operator-and-using-friend-function) and add template declaration in my code:

```
template <typename> class Point;
template <typename T> bool operator== (Point<T>, Point<T>);
template <class T>
class Point
{
private:
    T x;
public:
    Point(T X) : x(X) {}

    friend bool operator== (Point cP1, Point cP2);
};

template <class T>
bool operator== (Point<T> cP1, Point<T> cP2)
{
    return (cP1.x == cP2.x)
}
```

However I still get a error: `unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl operator==(class Point<int>,class Point<int>)" (??8@YA_NV?$Point@H@@0@Z) referenced in function _main`

And when I take away **friend** from :

`friend bool operator== (Point cP1, Point cP2);`

and want it to be member function, there would be a another error:

`too many parameters for this function`

why?

Comment: Alternatively do the work of the `==` in a static function, and implement the friend operator inline in the class definition and just call the static funciton, which can be implemented later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**@Kühl**'s answer is the most permissive approach to declare a templated friend function of a templated class. However, there is one unapparent side effect of this approach: All template instantiations of `Point` are friends with all template instantiations of `operator==()`. An alternative is to make only the instantiation with the same type of `Point` a friend. Which is done by adding a `<T>` in the friend declaration of `operator==()`.

```
template <typename T> class Point;

template <typename S>
bool operator== (Point<S>, Point<S>);

template <typename T>
class Point {
    // ...
    friend bool operator==<T> (Point, Point);
};
```

**References**
http://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/templates.html

Comment: why add **<T>** after **operator==**? Initialize template function need not **<T>** instead template class.

Comment: I know... specialization

Comment: Try this with `operator<`.  Notice `operator<<T>` v.s. `operator< <T>` (notice the extra whitespace). The compiler thinks you're defining the ostream operator in the first case...
Brutal for code formatting software lol

Answer (score 4):

The declaration of the `operator==()` is a template. The declaration made  a `friend` is *not* a template but a non-template. To make the template `operator==()` a friend you need to make the friend declaration a template, too:

```
template <typename T> class Point;

template <typename S>
bool operator== (Point<S>, Point<S>);

template <typename T>
class Point {
    // ...
    template <typename S>
    friend bool operator== (Point<S>, Point<S>);
};
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of using a template `operator==` instead of a non-template friend? It certainly makes sense if we'd want to compare points of different types, `template<typename S1, typename S2> friend bool operator==(Point<S1>, Point<S2>);`.

Comment: @vsoftco: In this specific case I don't see an advantage. If the befriended function happens to be named it allows explicit specification of a template parameter (for operators the template parameter can be specified when using function call notation).

Comment: thanks!  now I know declare `operator==()` and declare `friend` are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky issue: the friend declaration in the class will define a **different** friend function **for each instantiation** of your class. In other words, `Point<int>` and `Point<double>` will give rise to 2 different non-template friend functions. On the other hand, the outside function is a template function, not related to the `friend` inside the class. Solution: define the friend function inside the class. Due to [friend name injection, it will be found successfully by ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831077/why-does-friend-function-found-successfully-via-adl).

Answer (score -1):

You have to put `friend` classes within each other, as well as in themselves. The Real one is named syntactically the same without replacing expressions. So `friend bool operator==(P<T>,P<T>);` goes in both of the classes. So put `friend` before bool in the class T :-)

Comment: if `operator==` goes in both of the classes, I think it does not affect to call it.

Comment: If you read The C++  Language by Bjarne, it states that one should be of the class it's in and th other should be the exact same. They should both be friends,